# How do I use the RISC-V Vector (RVV) instructions in LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, riscv

In [this presentation](https://llvm.org/devmtg/2019-04/slides/TechTalk-Kruppe-Espasa-RISC-V_Vectors_and_LLVM.pdf) Kruppe and Espasa give an overview of the RISC-V Vector extension (RVV) and on [slide 16](https://llvm.org/devmtg/2019-04/slides/TechTalk-Kruppe-Espasa-RISC-V_Vectors_and_LLVM.pdf#page=16) they show LLVM IR samples which use the vector instructions through intrinsic functions, such as:

```
%vl = call i32 @llvm.riscv.vsetvl(i32 8)
```

At the time of the talk (April 2019) LLVM support for the V extension was developed out-of-tree at https://github.com/hanna-kruppe/rvv-llvm. However, that repository is archived now and the README file indicates that it is outdated since support for the RISC-V V extension is now developed upstream. I assume that this means that the features are now available from LLVM master at https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.

However, when I pull the current master and build it and try to compile the sample code with `llc` (specifying the target with `--mtriple=riscv32-unkown-none-rv32imv`), I get following error:

```
error: ../llvm-project/build/bin/llc: test.ll:4:18: error: use of undefined value '@llvm.riscv.vsetvl'
```

It seems that the V extension is available, since `llc -march=riscv32 -mattr=help` lists it:

```
Available features for this target:
...
  experimental-v           - 'V' (Vector Instructions).
```

Do I have to explicitly enable target features that are marked as experimental? Are these vector intrinsics shown in the slides even present in the upstream version? If yes, how do I use them? If no, how do I then use vector instructions in LLVM IR?

---

Follow-up: in [this post](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2018-September/126446.html) Eli Friedman explains that target-specific intrinsics should be defined in `include/llvm/IR/IntrinsicsRISCV.td`, and indeed in the [archived out-of-tree repository](https://github.com/hanna-kruppe/rvv-llvm) that file contains some [vector-specific intrinsics](https://github.com/hanna-kruppe/rvv-llvm/blob/rvv-2018-11-01/include/llvm/IR/IntrinsicsRISCV.td#L40) which are not present in [the upstream version](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/llvm/include/llvm/IR/IntrinsicsRISCV.td). If these intrinsics have not been ported upstream, what is then the correct way to use the RISC-V vector instructions?

Comment: Is there any update on this topic since last year?

Comment: @fabian Yes, support for vector intrinsics has been merged in the mean time and can be used by enabling the V extension: `llc -mtriple riscv32 -mattr=+experimental-v -o test.S test.ll`

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. I am coming from the riscv-gnu-toolchain wanting to use LLVM instead now. So I am somewhat new to LLVM. Can you point me to some resources on how to set up a RISC-V toolchain with vector support for rvv1.0 (intrinsics or inline assembly)? I am looking to go from C/C++ all the way to RISC-V binary/elf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked on the [LLVM developper's mailing list](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2020-October/146174.html): currently (Nov 2020) there is only MC layer (i.e. assembly level) support for the RISC-V V extension in LLVM (so no intrinsics right now).

However, there is an [RFC](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2020-October/145850.html) and [patch](https://reviews.llvm.org/D89449) that adds initial support for vector load, store and integer add intrinsics, as well as the required infrastructure to generate `vsetvl[i]` instructions.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two riscv triple defined in `llvm/include/llvm/ADT/Triple.h`: riscv32 and riscv64.

By default `HasStdExtV` which is the flag corresponding to `experimental-v` in initialized to false in `llvm/lib/Target/RISCV/RISCVSubtarget.h`, if you want to use this extension you need to enable this feature.

Clangs seems also supporting this feature. In `clang/lib/Driver/ToolChains/Arch/RISCV.cpp` you can see that march support `v` feature and generate `experimental-v` for llc.

There is nothing in `include/llvm/IR/IntrinsicsRISCV.td` about Vector extension , however you can find the description of the  instructions from the standard 'V' Vector
extension in `llvm/lib/Target/RISCV/RISCVInstrInfoV.td`. **It still experimental**. In clang also you can find that even if the v extension is supported, in the default you can see `// Currently LLVM supports only "mafdc".` in `clang/lib/Driver/ToolChains/Arch/RISCV.cpp`

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out, I do now explicitly enable the V extension with `-mtriple=riscv32 -mattr=+experimental-v` in `llc` and with `-menable-experimental-extensions -march=rv32imv0p9` in `clang`. Yet it seems that the extension cannot actually be used, since the lack of intrinsics means the vector instructions cannot be used in LLVM IR. Unless there is another way that does not involve intrinsics?

Comment: @kassiopeia what about inline assembler or writing your vector function in assembly language (i.e. compiler the `.s` file with clang then as separate translation unit)? Perhaps this is already supported by LLVM/clang.

Comment: @maxschlepzig I asked on the LLVM dev mailing list and was told that currently there is only MC layer (i.e. assembly level) support for RISC-V V instructions, so yes, I can use vector instructions in assembly code. However, I was hoping to use LLVM's register allocation and instruction scheduling functionality, which is currently not possible.