# How to print the total of positive and negative numbers in RISC-V Assembly

Tags: assembly, riscv

The program stores an array of 25 integers (words). Then calculate the sum of the positive numbers and the sum of the negative numbers, then print the total of both positive and negative numbers.

Error Messages:

```html
Error in /Users/COD/subtractandadd.asm line 76 column 15: "v0": operand is of incorrect type
Error in /Users/COD/subtractandadd.asm line 80 column 15: "v0": operand is of incorrect type
Error in /Users/COD/subtractandadd.asm line 81 column 12: "la": Too many or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: la t1,label  
Error in /Users/COD/subtractandadd.asm line 85 column 15: "v0": operand is of incorrect type
Error in /Users/COD/subtractandadd.asm line 89 column 15: "v0": operand is of incorrect type
Error in /Users/COD/subtractandadd.asm line 90 column 12: "la": Too many or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: la t1,label  
Error in /Users/COD/subtractandadd.asm line 92 column 11: "v0": operand is of incorrect type
```

Print and Exit Code:

```html
    #exit and print     
    exit:
   
          #print the positive numbers total
                   li v0,4
                   la a0,totalPositive
                   ecall
                   #print the +ve sum
                   li v0,1
                   la a0,($s1)
                   ecall 
    
         #print the negative total
                   li v0,4
                   la a0,totalNegative
                   ecall
                   #print the -ve sum
                   li v0,1
                   la a0,($s2)
                   ecall
               li v0,10 #end of program exit
               ecall
```

Comment: Can you give the compiler you are using and the arch abi information please?

Comment: What command did you issue that printed your error message? Please inform what compiler/assembler and toolchain you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using v0 registers which are only available with vector extension. If you toolchain.

The compiler and the "standard" binutils of the gnu toolchain don't seem supporting it yet. There is a dedicated binutils branch https://github.com/riscv/riscv-binutils-gdb/tree/rvv-1.0.x.

LLVM also is not supporting it also. [How do I use the RISC-V Vector (RVV) instructions in LLVM IR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64099125/how-do-i-use-the-risc-v-vector-rvv-instructions-in-llvm-ir/64127772#64127772)